# Is there a way to remove merged branches from my feature branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a feature branch I started about 2 months ago.  Occasionally, I have been merging in master to my feature branch to make sure it would still work with the production site.  Now that I'm finished, someone wants to see *only* the work I did on the feature branch.  Is there a way to remove the merges of master I have made so that the diff would only contain my work on the feature branch?

Comment: were there conflicts during merges?

Comment: Why can't they checkout your feature branch?

Comment: @OznOg nope,no conflicts

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon the feature branch on github now shows the merged in commits as well so it's hard to decipher which are mine

Comment: You could `git revert` the merges

Comment: from branch, I would try `git rebase $(git merge-base branch master)`

Comment: I would rebase your feature branch to master then

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. Since this is Github the simplest would be to [put up your branch as a draft Pull Request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests). Then they can use the Github review tools to view your changes and commits.

Your reviewer can use use the normal Git tools to look at your changes. The revision selection `master..<your branch>` will select commits which are reachable from your branch excluding those reachable from master; that means it will only reference the commits on your branch. It will show the merge commits, but not what has been merged. So `git diff master..<your branch>` to see the diff and `git log master..<your branch>` to see just your commits. See [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more.

If you truly want to eliminate the update merges you can [rebase your commits on top of master](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-git-rebase). This will effectively rewrite your branch as if you wrote it on top of the current version of master all along. There might be conflicts. While this is a good option to clean up your history, I do it myself regularly, it's very easy to get confused. I don't recommend this option if you're still learning Git and don't have an expert handy to guide you through the potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if your `feature` branch was branched off `develop` for example, you would do

```
git diff develop..feature
```

and the see overall diff brought by `feature` commits which are not on `develop`.

Alternatively, you could use the same range of refspecs (`develop..feature`) to feed to `git log` and obtain the commits themselves. I guess it depends on your review process.

---

**Edit after comments :**

(redacted, my answer was suboptimal because the cherry-pick would have brought back the merge commits. Go for a rebase like Schwern suggests)

Comment: thanks!  Is there anyway to remove them though rather than just see the diff in console?

Comment: I'm not too sure about what you mean by that... remove them ...from the output, right? (or from the branch?)

Comment: remove them from the branch and then force push that feature branch to github so that it correctly reflects only work

Comment: Make a new branch that is the same as feature (so you don't break it) then on each commit that merges master `git revert <sha>`

Comment: You could also do this with a `git rebase -I <sha_where_branched_from_master>`. This will be cleaner in the logs. Definitely create a new branch if you're doing this. It rewrites history.